# C compiler broken: is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c, cmake, mingw, clion

On my Dektop and on my Surface Pro 6 CLion has stopped working and I don´t know exactly why.

That is written on my Desktop:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Clion\übung 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0 
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.3.2/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message): 
The C compiler

"C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Clion/Ã¼bung/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp 

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_254a1/fast" 
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_254a1.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_254a1.dir/build 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Clion/Â³bung/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' 
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_254a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj 
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_254a1.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Clion\â”œâ•�bung\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c 
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Clion\â”œâ•�bung\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory 
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated. 
CMakeFiles\cmTC_254a1.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_254a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_254a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Clion/Â³bung/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' 
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_254a1/fast' failed 
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_254a1/fast] Error 2 
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. 
Call Stack (most recent call first): 
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
See also "C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Clion/Ã¼bung/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
See also "C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Clion/Ã¼bung/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And for my Surface Pro 6:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\CLion\udemy-übung-arrays 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.1.0 
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe 
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.3.2/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message): 
The C compiler

"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/CLion/udemy-Ã¼bung-arrays/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_d8abd/fast" 
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8abd.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8abd.dir/build 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/CLion/udemy-Â³bung-arrays/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' 
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8abd.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-P\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8abd.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\CLion\udemy-â”œâ•�bung-arrays\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c 
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\CLion\udemy-â”œâ•�bung-arrays\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory 
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated. 
CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8abd.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8abd.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8abd.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/CLion/udemy-Â³bung-arrays/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' 
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_d8abd/fast' failed 
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_d8abd/fast] Error 2 
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. 
Call Stack (most recent call first): 
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
See also "C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/CLion/udemy-Ã¼bung-arrays/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
See also "C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/CLion/udemy-Ã¼bung-arrays/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

[Failed to reload]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: the problem is in the file name, obviously. Something funny is happening with unicode letters there. I guess you named the folder Übung? Try calling it `exercise` instead

Answer (score 0):

Check out the previous answer to the title: How to use CMAKE in MinGW or MinGW-w64 to compile Clion:

[CLion: Error:The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883383/clion-errorthe-c-compiler-c-mingw-bin-gcc-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simp)

The answer is: you shouldn't let `sh.exe` in your `PATH` environment variable, it's [known to cause problem.](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/platform_dependent_issues/MinGW-Compiler-Issues)

Or to use [ninja](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases) as an alternative to make.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid special characters and spaces in paths, in your case `übung` is not a good idea.

GCC on Windows will not handle these paths properly.

Also I see you're using GCC 6 and 7, which are quite outdated. You can get more recent versions of MinGW-w64 GCC builds for Windows from https://winlibs.com/